# R: Obtaining a Sample and putting it into a Group

Tags: r

So basically I've got to get a random sample from a standard normal distribution, (call it x) then I had to order it, and put the ordered vector into 10 groups where the first group contains the 10 lowest and so on. Now I have to create a new vector such that in the order of x, the value in y is the group number that the value of x is in. I.e say the first 3 values in x were in groups 2,5 & 4 respectively, then the first 3 values in y is 2,5,4...
Can anyone give some assistance with my code and see where I've gone wrong?

```
x<-rnorm(100, mean=0, sd =1)
y<-(c(x))
datart<-x[order(x)]
datart
v1<-datart[1:10]
v2<-datart[11:20]
v3<-datart[21:30]
v4<-datart[31:40]
v5<-datart[41:50]
v6<-datart[51:60]
v7<-datart[61:70]
v8<-datart[71:80]
v9<-datart[81:90]
v10<-datart[91:100]
for (i in y)
{
    if (i<-v1) print(1)
    else if (i<-v2) print(2)
    else if (i<-ve) print(3)
    else if (i<-v4) print(4)
    else if (i<-v5) print(5)
    else if (i<-v6) print(6)
    else if (i<-v7) print(7)
    else if (i<-v8) print(8)
    else if (i<-v9) print(9)
    else if (i<-v10) print(10)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one-liner, to adapt for a different number of groups or different group sizes.

```
x   <- rnorm(100)
out <- rep(1:10, each = 10)[order(order(x))]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
res <- cut(x, quantile(x, seq(0, 1, 0.1)), 
         labels=paste0("v", 1:10), 
         include.lowest=TRUE)

table(res)
#res
# v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9 v10 
# 10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

`?cut` will divide the vector into groups. `?quantile` is used to create bins for grouping, `seq(0, 1, .1)` will divide the distribution into deciles as in the example. The `labels` argument allows naming of the bins. `include.lowest` will set the lower bound to "greater-than or equal to" instead of just "greater than".

If you would like to access a group with the numbers as output there are multiple options (named vectors, data.frame, vector subsetting), it just depends on what you would like to do next:

We can create a list with all of the groups separated:

```
split(x, res)
# $v1
#  [1] -1.880931 -2.030636 -1.744457 -1.488322
#  [5] -1.235983 -2.436656 -1.604551 -1.380327
#  [9] -1.418812 -1.737736
# 
# $v2
#  [1] -1.2147030 -0.8343691 -0.8357011 -1.2101051
#  [5] -1.1952688 -0.9705542 -0.8684121 -0.9311926
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(777)
x <- rnorm(100)
```